# What does the exclamation mark do?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I've seen this but never knew what it does. Can any one let me in on the details? Thanks.

Comment: One of my students: "What is $7!$... is it like SEVEN?!?!"

Comment: @TheChaz: in a high squeaky voice? ;)

Comment: @J. M. - Not exactly! He was actually one of the bigger college students that I've worked with... I used to run into Thomas at the gym every so often.

Comment: "Among the worst of barabarisms is that of introducing    symbols which are quite new in mathematical, but perfectly     understood in common, language. Writers have borrowed from the     Germans the abbreviation n! to signify 1.2.3.(n - 1).n, which
gives their pages the appearance of expressing surprise and    admiration that 2, 3, 4, &c. should be found in mathematical results." - Augustus de Morgan, 1842.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably you're thinking about the symbol for the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) function:
$$n! = 1\times 2 \times 3\times \cdots \times (n-1) \times n$$

Answer (score 15):

An exclamation mark can also be shorthand for "unique". For example, the statement
$$\forall y\in f(A), \exists!x\in A \text{ s.t. } y=f(x)$$
would be read as "for all $y$ in the range of $f$, there exits a unique $x$ in the domain such that $y=f(x)$". In other words, $f$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 5):

...or possibly [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) $n!! = n \times (n-2) \times (n-4) \times \cdots $, or maybe [subfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html), $!n$, also known as [derangement number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

**Added** ... and [superfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superfactorial.html) for desert.

Comment: the superfactorial has little rainfall? :-)

Comment: ...and there's even a hyperfactorial, too. :)

Answer (score 5):

For completeness:

Although in mathematics the $!$ almost always refers to the factorial function, you often see it in quasi-mathematical contexts with a different meaning.

For example, in many programming languages it is used to mean negation, for example in Java the expression `!true` evaluates to `false`. It is also commonly used to express inequality, for example in the expression `1 != 2`, read as '1 is not equal to 2'.

It is also used in some functional languages to denote a function that modifies its input, as in the function `set!` in Scheme, which sets its first argument to the value of its second argument.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add a common usage for it as well since that may be of more interest to you.

A common usage for the factorial is in permutations.

For example:
If there were 3 people in a race, how many possible ways could there be to arrange the ranking.

The answer would be 3! (3 factorial) or 3 x 2 x 1 or 6 ways.

Listing them the brute force way:
1) A,B,C

2)A,C,B

3)B,A,C

4)B,C,A

5)C,A,B

6)C,B,A

This extends into a lot of other things but most commonly associated with statistics, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If it is $6!$, it would be $6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$, if it was $9!$, it would be $9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$. Do you see the pattern?
$$6! = 720\\
9!= 362,880.$$

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please take a look on [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I'll edit your post, and you can see all changes pressing edit button, but do formatting yourself in the future.